# Как с помощью js выделить слово на котором стоит курсор мыши?

Tags: javascript

Предположим есть какойто текст в текстовом поле (`textarea` или `div[contenteditable="true"]`), пользователь ткнул мышкой на какое-то слово, курсор находится в середине слова.
Как сделать что бы по нажатию кнопки слово выделилось ?

p.s. знаю что смотреть нужно в сторону getRangeObject

Comment: Есть ведь двойной щелчок мышью по слову. Этого недостаточно?

Comment: Ахаха, нет, мне просто нужно чтобы скрипт сам делал это, а потом производил какие либо манипуляции с выделеной облостью

Comment: Нужно выделить слово с помощью js?

Comment: да, ну разве по заголовку непонятно ?

Comment: Что, если попробовать обернуть каждое слово внутри contenteditable в div и при клике на div выделять его. Подумай в этом направлении. К сожалению, приводить конкретный код нет времени.

Comment: нет, такое не подходит, изменять html нельзя (

Comment: тогда пиши код, который вручную определяет то, на каком слове сейчас находится курсор)